# Add a "autocomplete" field in a buildForm

Tags: 8, entities

How do I add an autocomplete field in a class that extends `FormBase`?

I created a custom module, which uses a class that extends `FormBase`. I want to  programmatically create a form field that autocompletes the username from the user registered in the site.

Answer (score 10):

You use *entity_autocomplete* as #type for the form field. [`CommentForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21CommentForm.php/function/CommentForm%3A%3Aform/8.2.x) contains such a form field, for the administrator users to be able to change the author of a comment. This is the code it uses.

```
  // The uid field is only displayed when a user with the permission
  // 'administer comments' is editing an existing comment from an
  // authenticated user.
  $owner = $comment->getOwner();
  $form['author']['uid'] = [
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#target_type' => 'user',
    '#default_value' => $owner->isAnonymous() ? NULL : $owner,
    // A comment can be made anonymous by leaving this field empty therefore
    // there is no need to list them in the autocomplete.
    '#selection_settings' => ['include_anonymous' => FALSE],
    '#title' => $this->t('Authored by'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Leave blank for %anonymous.', ['%anonymous' => $config->get('anonymous')]),
    '#access' => $is_admin,
  ];
```

As you can see from the code, you can also choose to include the anonymous user.

The result is shown in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8.0 provides a form element specifically for autocomplete with any entity (implemented by the [`EntityAutocomplete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Element!EntityAutocomplete.php/class/EntityAutocomplete/8) class), and has some changes for custom autocomplete.

Look at the [Drupal Change Records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal) and search for *autocomplete* in the *Keyword* field; you will get a list of changes for Drupal 8. There is a change record that lists the changes for a [custom autocomplete functionality by using the form properties #autocomplete_route_name and #autocomplete_parameters](https://www.drupal.org/node/2070985).

So with that information you should be able to add an [entity autocomplete element](https://www.drupal.org/node/2418529) in your form for users.

Comment: +1 on documenting your way of finding this but you might to include a code sample too from the last link otherwise someone will comment that you should do so. Which I just did ;)